# WM_CHAR lParam extended key (24 bit) always 0

Tags: c++, winapi, bit-manipulation

I'm trying get extended key state

```
WNDPROC lpfnEditWndProc; 

//edit - hwnd of edit control
lpfnEditWndProc = (WNDPROC) SetWindowLong(edit, GWL_WNDPROC, (DWORD) SubClassProc); 


struct Bits {
    WORD nRepeatCount: 16;
    BYTE nScanCode : 8;
    BYTE nExtended : 1;
    BYTE nReserved : 4;
    BYTE nContext : 1;
    BYTE nPrevious : 1;
    BYTE nTransition : 1;
  };


union KeyInfo
{  
  LPARAM lParam;
  Bits bits;  
};


LRESULT CALLBACK SubClassProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
     switch (msg) { 
          case WM_CHAR: 
          {
              KeyInfo v;
              v.lParam = lParam;

              printf("nExtended = %d\n", v.bits.nExtended);
          }
          break;

     }

     return CallWindowProc(lpfnEditWndProc, hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam); 
}
```

**nExtended always == 0**

I tried to turn out information in the different ways, like `(lParam << 24) & 1;`

all the same nExtended  == 0

Win7 64 bit, Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Left or right ctrl + C or V, or any key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for WM_CHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276.aspx) says:

> Because there is not necessarily a one-to-one
>   correspondence between keys pressed and character
>   messages generated, the information in the high-order
>   word of the lParam parameter is generally not useful to
>   applications. The information in the high-order word applies
>   only to the most recent WM_KEYDOWN message that precedes the posting of the WM_CHAR message.

You will have to process the WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP messages to get extended key information.

Comment: I tried this code for WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP, and it is still not working.nExtended == 0

Comment: No, it works fine for WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP. Press the right hand alt or ctrl and bit 24 will be set.